# Saving password to the database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to ask how to save a user's password to the database? I've done it but the result is saved to the database is not the same as the password was entered. and password that instead turned into a strange code that long. even though I've been using the action 'md5'. correction please what is wrong with my syntax controllers.thanks before

```
function add(){
    $data['title']="Add user";
    $this->_set_rules();

    if($this->form_validation->run()==true){
        $kode=$this->input->post('username'); 
        $cek=$this->m_user->cek($kode); 
        if($cek->num_rows()>0){
            $data['message']="<div class='alert alert-danger'>Username is already in use/div>";
            $this->template->display('admin/adduser',$data);
        }else{

            $info=array(
                'name'=>$this->input->post('name'),
                'addres'=>$this->input->post('addres'),
                'dateofbirth'=>$this->input->post('dateof birth'),
                'email'=>$this->input->post('email'),
                'username'=>$this->input->post('user'),
                'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),
                'level'=>$this->input->post('level')

            );

            $this->m_user->save($info);
            redirect('admin/user/add_success');

        }
    }else{
        $data['message']="";
        $this->template->display('admin/adduser',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: use model for db operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

md5 is a hashing algorithm which is hashing your password to the string of 32 char length.
that string is the hash of the password you entered. 
for ex if your password is abcd then md5(password) will be d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e.
remove that md5() to see your password

Answer (score 1):

If you are applying md5 to the input you have received via form post that means you want to encrypt your password in a secured format. md5() basically applies an encryption to generate a 32 character long text that is secure and not possible to decrypt.

Also this considered a good practice to follow this strategy but you need to be little bit careful before applying the same subject to your requirement and data.

Also if you don't want to apply this encryption then simply omit this method before the post variable:

```
 Before: 'password'=>md5($this->input->post('password')),//Gives encrypted 32 char long text
 After : 'password'=>($this->input->post('password'),    //Gives plain text
```